# How to get informative data in smart contract with using API in R

Tags: r, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, etherscan

I want to get informative data about the contract with using API.

I found hash address with using Etherscan. I copied the contract to the R. But I don't know how to get informative data (such as  balance, token info etc.)

My screen look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts are written in Solidity programming language. Solidity programming language is not R programming language. You just cannot copy paste stuff from one language for another.

The correct answer is to run Ethereum node and use JSON-RPC API. But seems like your starting level of programming knowledge is too low for this, so recommend doing basic programming courses and learning before trying to try anything this complex.